# Comparing two text files containing groups of data

Tags: python, file, compare

I have two text files containing groups of data. The groups are organized by 4 lines of data followed by a space in between each group. I'm trying to compare the sets in file 1 with the sets in file 2 and then extract the sets NOT found in file 2; however, I have no idea how to keep the data so they stay in groups. This is an example of how the data looks:

```
Data 1
Data 2
Number 1
Number 2

Data 1
Data 2
Number 1
Number 2
```

and it repeats. Here is what I have so far:

```
f1 = open("file 1.txt","r").readlines()
f2 = open("file 2.txt","r").readlines()

diff = set(f1) - set(f2)
print diff 
outFile = open("output.txt","w")
outFile.writelines(line for line in f1 if line in diff)
```

Comment: Do you want to find the lines, which are not in file 1 and then those lines you want to write in output.txt?

Comment: I want to find the lines which are not in file 2 and write those in the outfile. What is happening is the lines would be extracted but they would not stay together in the same data set.

Comment: i have something, but i didnt do it with sets, do want to see it ?

Comment: Have you tried difflib http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Comment: That would be great! Thanks T.C.!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to compare groups of lines between the two files, and not just the lines in the files. In this case, you'll needs to group the lines together yourself, and then do the compare as you've done. Assuming there is always a blank line between the groups (as you've posted), the below reads one of the files. The lines should still have their `\n` on them, so printing out the final data shouldn't need any special formatting

```
allLines = open("file1.txt", 'r').readlines()

# this is the array you'll want to compare with
groupedLines = []
gLine = ""

for line in allLines:
    # whenever you get a blank line, put the grouped line in the array
    # and clear the grouped line
    if line == "":
        groupedLines.append(gLine)
        gLine = ""
    gLine += line

# don't forget to save the last grouping
groupedLines.append(gLine)
```

Comment: lists will not play nicely with the elegant set-based method of substracting the groups. better to create the groups as hashable tuples right away.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. But perhaps a more sophisticated parser may be called for if your problem start becoming more complex.

```
text1 = """
Data 1
Data 2
Number 1
Number 2

Data 1
Data 2
Number 5
Number 6
"""

text2 = """
Data 1
Data 2
Number 1
Number 2

Data 1
Data 2
Number 3
Number 4
"""

from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """recipe from itertools docs"""
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def line_group(text):
    """remove empty lines, and split per 4"""
    return grouper((line for line in text.splitlines() if line), 4)

print set(line_group(text1)) - set(line_group(text2))
```